# iOS - Persistent Variable to Track Global Setting

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, struct

In an app I'm making I'm trying to track which index of an array is the current index. Tracking this info is important is it will prevent redundant API calls if the selected index is the same as the already loaded index.

I have made a Struct with a static var to track the current array index, however it seems to only hold the value on one page of the app.

My app has a tab bar with 3 tabs. On Tab 1 this is working fine, however on Tab 2 the Struct var gets set, however if I go to Tab 1 or 3 and then back to 2, it's back to -1 (which is the "default").

I have my Struct built like so:

```
struct currentDefault {
    static var cDefault:Int = -1
}
```

And then I create it on each page like this:

```
var setIndex = currentDefault.cDefault
```

My check function looks identical on each page:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated:Bool) {
    var index = Load.defaultEnterprise("defaultEnterprise")
    if index != self.setIndex || self.setIndex == -1 {
        loadPlayerList()
        currentDefault.cDefault = index
    }
}
```

In the above example, "index" is loaded from the user's current default setting.
On the initial page load setIndex would be -1, which is fine, however after that the Struct's static var should hold the current index.

Is there a better to globally track the array index between all pages of an app? If a Struct is the way to go, any reason why it's defaulting on each page load?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by doing the following:

My Struct:

```
struct currentDefault {
    static var playlistDefault:Int = -1
    static var playerDefault:Int = -1
}
```

My viewWillAppear (different struct var on each tab):

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated:Bool) {
    var index = Load.defaultEnterprise("defaultEnterprise")
    if index != currentDefault.playlistDefault {
        loadPlaylists()
        currentDefault.playlistDefault = index
    }
}
```

I removed the "var setIndex" from each page as well, as I think creating a var referencing a Struct var that has a default value MAY inherit it's default value and not it's updated value. Not sure about that entirely, though.

Anyhow, that's what worked.